# replace number in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match this string

```
'12.34.5.6',#### OR
'12.34.5.6', #### (Note the space after the comma)
```

in a series of files and replace #### with 2222.

I started small and this command successfully changed 1234 to 2222

```
sed -i 's/'12.34.5.6\''\,1234/'12.34.5.6\''\, 2222/g' file.txt
```

so I moved on to work on replacing 1234 with regex, below are some of the commands i've tried but do not work.

```
sed -i 's/'12.34.5.6\''\,\(\s?[0-9]{4,5}\)/'12.34.5.6\''\, 2222/g' file.txt
sed -i 's/'12.34.5.6\''\,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?/'12.34.5.6\''\, 2222/g' file.txt
```

Can someone help me out with this or give some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
sed -E "s/('12.34.5.6',\s?)[0-9]{4,5}/\12222/g"
```

**Examples:**

```
$ echo "'12.34.5.6', 2134" | sed -E "s/('12.34.5.6',\s?)[0-9]{4,5}/\12222/g"
'12.34.5.6', 2222
$ echo "'12.34.5.6',9230" | sed -E "s/('12.34.5.6',\s?)[0-9]{4,5}/\12222/g"
'12.34.5.6',2222
```

**Explications:**

With `-E` we ask `sed` to use [extended regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) (but this is mainly a matter of taste), the beginning of the regex is fairly simple: `'12.34.5.6',` just match this same string. We then add a space, followed by a `?` to indicate it is optionnal. This first part is enclosed in braces to be able to use this in the replacement pattern.

Then, we add the `#`'s to the pattern. I assumed you used `#`'s in place of numbers based on your attempts with `[0-9]{4,5}` and `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Finally, in the replacement pattern we use the previously matched first pair of braces with `\1`, and add our `2`'s: `\12222` (which will replace the numbers (`#`'s), discarded in the process because not enclosed in the braces).

PS. Next time please [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for better readability.
PPS. I think the real issue here is not the regex but the quote escaping in your regex. Maybe take look at [this question].

Comment: Thanks for your response. What does #{4} mean in the command and what does \1 in \12222 mean ?

Comment: I updated my answer, I didn't understand that by `#` you really were expecting to match numbers. The `\1` means "first capturing group" (ie. everything matched by the first group of braces).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried out your example but I am getting this error: char 36: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS. I tried escaping the quotes and editing the command but still getting an error one way or another.

Comment: Thank you for your help GuillaumeA.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "s/('12[.]34[.]5[.]6',[ ]?)[0-9]{4}/\\12222/g"
```